# Change Highchart Options dynamically in angular

Tags: angular, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I've seen a few answers online but none that seem to apply to angular.

I have [an example with a simple chart and two series](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highcharts-dynamic-options?file=src/app/app.component.ts). I want the toggle to toggle the visability of the second series.

```
this.chartOptions.series[1].visible = true|false;
```

but this doesn't trigger the chart to redraw. And since I defined the chart in the Angular html template I don't think I can re-instantiated the chart element like the docs suggest.

Can anyone help me toggle the chart to redraw?

Comment: stackblitz link has changed

Comment: Redraw callback function in docs: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw. Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-load/

Comment: I think that this demo from official Highcharts Angular documentation should help you to implement the update event in your chart: https://codesandbox.io/s/k24qxvzlk7 docs: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular. If not - could you share your stackblitz again? Current link doesn't work.

Comment: Updated the link... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I screwed up and posted an invalid link, but Nathaniel pointed me in the right direction.

I just needed to set the update flag to true.